# Do you get differentiated data from Google Optimize A/B test with multiple user targeting variables?

Tags: usability-testing, data

If you target test variations for your users with Google Optimize will you get differentiated values for those variations such as mobile, tablet, location and so on in one single A/B test, or we just receive a bulk data test result?

Answer (score 0):

When you AB test is complete you can can than view the segmentation of this data on Google Analytics. From there you can add additional filters such as device, region etc.

The overview Optimize is great so perhaps as this these details in how your going to score the test but don't be concerned if you forget, you can always dig deeper after the test.

Comment: Hiya. That really helped. Thank you so much. Regards, Estela